# Why is this AWS Event Triggering shell script unable to invoke lambda function, and SNS topic?

Tags: shell, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

[This](https://github.com/iam-veeramalla/shell-scripting-projects/blob/main/aws-event-triggering/s3-notification-triggers.sh) is the shell script that I used:

Following is the output that is baffling me despite replacing the $aws-account-id with my Account ID. What could be the reasons causing these errors and their remedies too please?

[O/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjDTz.png)

[O/p (continued)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bYcR.png)

Apart from the S3 bucket, no other resource is created post the script execution.